# Can't remote login after startup

Tags: sleep-wake, ssh, screen-sharing, restart

I have an iMac running Catalina (10.15.2) that I don't have a keyboard or mouse plugged into. I just want to use it via screen sharing and SSH.

The problem is that often when I want to use it I can't. SSH hangs, screen sharing won't connect. I've tried restarting it via the power button, but even when it gets to the login screen I can't use SSH or screen sharing.

The only thing that seems to work is plugging in a keyboard and mouse, and logging in the normal way. Then SSH and screen sharing start working. They continue to work for a while. Eventually I come back and it's back in a bad state.

In Energy Saver settings I checked "Prevent computer from sleeping" and "Wake for network access" as well as "Start up automatically after power failure", power nap and hard disk sleep are unchecked.

Comment: I can see this happening via Screen Sharing (it's VNC after all) but not via SSH.  If you leave your mouse/keyboard plugged in, after the period of time this usually happens, can you log in then?  What about a 3rd party offering like TeamViewer?  Does this problem present with them as well?

Comment: I left it overnight without mouse and keyboard and I can still remote login. I suspect the issue is that it only doesn't work after restart. So the times it breaks are when it auto-updates or loses power.

Comment: Do you manually start services when you restart?  Try restarting.  SSH has exactly zero to do with your mouse/keyboard

Comment: Obviously. The issue is that _I have to log in manually_ before SSH works. I do not manually start the services, they seem to start on login, but I want them to be available on startup so that I don't have to plug in a mouse and keyboard to log in.

Comment: Are you using the built in SSH or a 3rd party variant?  Did you upgrade SSH from Homebrew or something?

Comment: Built-in SSH, no homebrew.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by having FileVault enabled in the security settings. The disk won't decrypt until someone logs in, so services like remote desktop and sshd won't start until then.